# Display all matched records using Oracle Query

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have query in Oracle using Connect by Level to display all matched records with regexp_substr but it doesn’t display all, I need to change the Connect by Level from +1 to +8 to get all the result. What if the matches are more than that in the future? I want to capture regardless how many matches without changing the +1 to +10 or +20, etc. Is there any easiest and fastest approach?

Here’s my query:

```
SELECT     DATA_SOURCE,REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA_SOURCE,'A-\S+|ABC\S+',1, LEVEL) AS REF_NUM
FROM
(
SELECT '
Z-TEST
Y-TEST
A-123456789
ABC123456790
Y-TRY
A-123456791
ABC123456792
ABC123456793
Y-TRY
Y-TRY
Z-TEST
Y-TEST
Z-TEST
Y-TEST
A-123456794
ABC123456795
ABC123456796
Y-TRY
Z-TEST
Y-TEST
Z-TEST
Y-TEST
A-123456797
ABC123456798
' DATA_SOURCE
FROM DUAL
)
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(REGEXP_COUNT(DATA_SOURCE,'A-\S+|ABC\S+'))+1

Result: 
A-123456789
ABC123456790
A-123456791

Desired Result:
REF_NUM
A-123456789
ABC123456790
A-123456791
ABC123456792
ABC123456793
A-123456794
ABC123456795
ABC123456796
A-123456797
ABC123456798
```

Comment: Why are you comparing to the **length** of the count? If there are 8 results in the output, then the count is 8. The length of 8 is 1. ("Length" means how many digits are in the number - in this case, one digit.) Why would you compare anything to 1, and not to 8?

Comment: Besides that, are you sure your regular expression is correct? It will also return `A-123` if the inputs contain the string `DMA-123`, is that what you need?

Comment: Hi @mathguy, you are right the regex should be modified, I need only for those first string ‘^A-|^ABC’,1,1,’m’ I tried multiline function in Connect by Level doesn’t work! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connect by clause should be

```sql
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(DATA_SOURCE,'A-\S+|ABC\S+', 1)
```

instead of

```sql
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(REGEXP_COUNT(DATA_SOURCE,'A-\S+|ABC\S+'))+1
```

But if you want to apply this solution to a table with more rows, you will need to add this :

```sql
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(DATA_SOURCE,'A-\S+|ABC\S+', 1)
AND PRIOR DATA_SOURCE = DATA_SOURCE
AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
```

to your connect by clause.

So your query should ultimately be this :

```sql
SELECT     --DATA_SOURCE, 
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA_SOURCE,'A-\S+|ABC\S+',1, LEVEL) AS REF_NUM
FROM
(
SELECT '
Z-TEST
Y-TEST
A-123456789
ABC123456790
Y-TRY
A-123456791
ABC123456792
ABC123456793
Y-TRY
Y-TRY
Z-TEST
Y-TEST
Z-TEST
Y-TEST
A-123456794
ABC123456795
ABC123456796
Y-TRY
Z-TEST
Y-TEST
Z-TEST
Y-TEST
A-123456797
ABC123456798
' DATA_SOURCE
FROM DUAL
)
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(DATA_SOURCE,'A-\S+|ABC\S+', 1)
AND PRIOR DATA_SOURCE = DATA_SOURCE
AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
;
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=359f21ab0343257f2fb4ad2b706875e8)

[For further explanation](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/split-comma-separated-values-into-rows-in-oracle-database)

Comment: Hi @MDBIA, the result is only one even there are multiple matches with your query…

Comment: I am not sure I got you well, but I added a demo link to my answer. You can test it there.

Comment: Hi @MDBIA I saw the demo, yeah it works the way I wanted, I’ll check in actual query and let you know.

Comment: Hi @ClintMohamed, I updated my answer to cover multi rows cases.
Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi @MDBIA, the query you have shared a little bit faster, but my actual data has multiple A- and ABC anywhere in the field, I want to capture for those A- and ABC from the first character multi-line only, I tried my regexp to ‘^A-\S+|^ABC\S+’, 1, 1, ‘m’, Level) but it doesn’t work any suggestions?

Comment: Ok, if I got you well, you would need to replace respectively the first line of the connect by clause by REGEXP_COUNT(DATA_SOURCE,'^(A-|ABC)\S+', 1, 'm'), and the regexp_substr in the select clause by REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA_SOURCE,'^((A-|ABC)\S+)',1, LEVEL, 'm'). Please let me know if those changes work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Change connect by condition to e.g. number of `CHR(13)` appearances (line #35), and then select rows whose `ref_num` exists (line #38). Something like this:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     temp
  3     AS
  4        (    SELECT DATA_SOURCE,
  5                    REGEXP_SUBSTR (DATA_SOURCE,
  6                                   'A-\S+|ABC\S+',
  7                                   1,
  8                                   LEVEL) AS REF_NUM
  9               FROM (SELECT '
 10  Z-TEST
 11  Y-TEST
 12  A-123456789
 13  ABC123456790
 14  Y-TRY
 15  A-123456791
 16  ABC123456792
 17  ABC123456793
 18  Y-TRY
 19  Y-TRY
 20  Z-TEST
 21  Y-TEST
 22  Z-TEST
 23  Y-TEST
 24  A-123456794
 25  ABC123456795
 26  ABC123456796
 27  Y-TRY
 28  Z-TEST
 29  Y-TEST
 30  Z-TEST
 31  Y-TEST
 32  A-123456797
 33  ABC123456798
 34  ' DATA_SOURCE FROM DUAL)
 35         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (data_source, CHR (10)))
```

---

```
 36  SELECT ref_num
 37    FROM temp
 38   WHERE ref_num IS NOT NULL;

REF_NUM
--------------------
A-123456789
ABC123456790
A-123456791
ABC123456792
ABC123456793
A-123456794
ABC123456795
ABC123456796
A-123456797
ABC123456798

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]** If you're actually parsing table contents (not one *huge* string) at a time, then see if such an example helps. I split your sample data into two rows and added `ID` columns (just to make it simpler to review the result).

```
SQL> with your_table (id, data_source) as
  2  (select 1, '
  3  Z-TEST
  4  Y-TEST
  5  A-123456789
  6  ABC123456790
  7  Y-TRY
  8  A-123456791
  9  ABC123456792
 10  ABC123456793
 11  Y-TRY
 12  Y-TRY
 13  ' from dual
 14  union all
 15  select 2, '
 16  Z-TEST
 17  Y-TEST
 18  Z-TEST
 19  Y-TEST
 20  A-123456794
 21  ABC123456795
 22  ABC123456796
 23  Y-TRY
 24  Z-TEST
 25  Y-TEST
 26  Z-TEST
 27  Y-TEST
 28  A-123456797
 29  ABC123456798
 30  ' from dual
 31  )
```

---

```
 32  select id,
 33    regexp_substr (data_source, 'A-\S+|ABC\S+', 1, column_value) as ref_num
 34  from your_table cross join
 35    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 36                        connect by level <= regexp_count (data_source, chr (10))
 37                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 38  where regexp_substr (data_source, 'A-\S+|ABC\S+', 1, column_value) is not null
 39  /

        ID REF_NUM
---------- ------------------------------
         1 A-123456789
         1 ABC123456790
         1 A-123456791
         1 ABC123456792
         1 ABC123456793
         2 A-123456794
         2 ABC123456795
         2 ABC123456796
         2 A-123456797
         2 ABC123456798

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot, it works but the performance is so bad if parsing HugeClob. Any workaround to minimize the null records intead of disregarding through Where ref_num is not null…

Comment: Are you parsing just one huge CLOB, or are you parsing the whole table ("n" rows with CLOB column)? Because, if former, there's nothing much you can do about it, I'm afraid. If latter, then yes - it can be rewritten and - hopefully - made to run somewhat faster.

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot, I am parsing one col hugeclob for every record about 5,000 chars each record…

Comment: I added yet another example; have a look, please.

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot, thank you so much!